# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mailing Address Validation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, validation, address, cloudpagesurl

Good afternoon, does anyone know a way to verify mailing/postal address in marketing cloud? we have used address tool for SalesCloud but in this instance we want to use cloud pages to capture the postal address and want to be able to verify it. Somone suggested loqate but that seems to work only on commerce cloud.

Comment: There is nothing built in for SFMC as it is centered around Digital Marketing. You would need to validate using a 3rd party integration or tool.

Comment: Gortonington that makes sense, do you know a 3rd party app that offers the functionality?